# Javascript Adapter throwing java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: https, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to make a https call to the backend server that gives a json data , i could get the by making https calls using browser but when make the same call using the javascript adapter i getting this output
I followed this [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html) to add the cert to the default mobilefirst keystore. I am not sure why i am getting this error?

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project kmf]login/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project kmf]
Http request failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project kmf]java.net.SocketException: Connection resetjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:271)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:201)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:185
```

Comment: Connection reset means , the backend server has reset the connection. You should consult your network team/ backend team and verify why this occuring. Firewalls / network issues / backend server connection issues are all possibilities. MobileFirst server is only reporting the issue as it found

Answer (score -2):

From the comments, by Vivin:

> Connection reset means , the backend server has reset the connection. You should consult your network team/ backend team and verify why this occuring. Firewalls / network issues / backend server connection issues are all possibilities. MobileFirst server is only reporting the issue as it found